# How to multiply 100 Integers with another 100 integers in parallel on a GPU using PyOpenCL?

Tags: macos, parallel-processing, gpu, pyopencl

There are many PyopenCL examples on doing arithmetic operations on vectors of size 4. if I have to multiply 100 integers with another 100 integers all at once using AMD GPU on Mac through PyOpenCL, can someone provide and explain the code please? Since max vector size can be 16, I would like to know how can I ask the GPU to do this operation which needs processing more than 16 integers in parallel.

I have a AMD D500 firepro GPU.
Does every Work Item( thread)  perform a task independently, if yes there are 24 compute units and each compute unit has 255 work items for single dimension and [255,255,255] for three dimension. Does it mean my GPU has 6120 independent work items?

Comment: You should definitely do some reading on OpenCL's memory model before diving into using it with an API.

Answer (score 0):

I made a short example for an entry-wise multiplication of two one-dimensional integer arrays. Note that if you plan to multiply only 100 values it will not be faster than doing this on the CPU, since you have a lot of overhead with copying the data and so on.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

#this is compiled by the GPU driver and will be executed on the GPU
kernelsource = """  
__kernel void multInt(  __global int* res,
                        __global int* a,
                        __global int* b){
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    int N = get_global_size(0); //this is the dimension given as second argument in the kernel execution
    res[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
"""

device = cl.get_platforms()[0].get_devices()[0]
context = cl.Context([device])
program = cl.Program(context, kernelsource).build()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)

#preparing input data in numpy arrays in local memory (i.e. accessible by the CPU)
N = 100
a_local = np.array(range(N)).astype(np.int32)
b_local = (np.ones(N)*10).astype(np.int32)

#preparing result buffer in local memory
res_local = np.zeros(N).astype(np.int32)

#copy input data to GPU-memory
a_buf = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a_local)
b_buf = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=b_local)
#prepare result buffer in GPU-memory
res_buf = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, res_local.nbytes)
#execute previously compiled kernel on GPU
program.multInt(queue,(N,), None, res_buf, a_buf, b_buf)
#copy the result from GPU-memory to CPU-memory
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, res_local, res_buf)

print("result: {}".format(res_local))
```

For the documentation of PyOpenCL: Once you have understood the working principle of GPGPU programming and the programming concepts of OpenCL, PyOpenCL is pretty straightforward.